# Remix run hydration error only on index route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering, remix.run

I am starting a project on remix v2, when I test my code locally everything works fine. However, when I deploy my project to a EC2 server I get an error on my index route
`Initial URL (/index.html) does not match URL at time of hydration (/), reloading page...`
This only occurs on my index route and only occurs after a server side render. When I navigate to another page it works fine, and I click back to the index page it still works fine when using client side rendering. When I refresh, I see the error again. I also noticed when I create a route like `index[.].html.tsx` it would work, weirdly enough. Any reason why this might be happening?

npx remix routes output

```
<Routes>
  <Route file="root.tsx">
    <Route path="domain" index file="routes/domain._index.tsx" />
    <Route index file="routes/_index.tsx" />
    <Route path="*" file="routes/$.tsx" />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```